# nagios plugins and check ssh 1.29 and check ssh 1.414

Tags: nagios

I need to install check ssh 1.29 and check ssh 1.414 can anyone tell me what is the relationship between check ssh and nagios plugins and where i can download nagios plugins for windows

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The check_ssh program is part of the 'Offical Nagios Plugins' package.  It can be downloaded from this page: http://www.nagios.org/download/plugins
The current version is 1.4.16, there is a link on the page above for older versions as well.